# how to imputin continuous range of dates in a column of SAS EG table for each of var in other column

Tags: sas

I want to add continuous dates in the column 'Date' for each of unique value in the column 'V1'. And below explains what I am doing and what error i am getting (unable to impute dates).

I have a table as shown below:

```
V1          Date
MS000328    04JAN16
MS000328    08JAN16
MS000328    12JAN16
MS000328    08FEB16
MS000328    09FEB16
MS000328    12MAR16
MS000328    15MAR16
MS000328    16APR16
MS000328    17APR16
MS000329    02JAN16
MS000329    16JAN16
MS000329    29JAN16
MS000329    03FEB16
MS000329    19FEB16
MS000329    21MAR16
MS000329    31MAR16
MS000329    11APR16
MS000329    19APR16
```

What I want something like this:

```
V1          Date
MS000328    01JAN16
MS000328    02JAN16
MS000328    03JAN16
MS000328    04JAN16
MS000328    05JAN16
MS000328    06JAN16
MS000328    07JAN16
MS000328    08JAN16
.
.
.
.
.
MS000329    01JAN16
MS000329    02JAN16
MS000329    03MAR16
.
.
MS000329    01APR16
MS000329    02APR16
.
.
MS000329    01MAR16
MS000329    02MAR16
.
.
MS000329    01APR16
MS000329    02APR16
.
.
.
```

I am using the follwing code....

```
data want1 (keep = V1 Date);
   set have;
   by V1;
run;

data want;
   set want1;
   format Date date.;
   Date = "1JAN2016"d;
   do i = 0 to 365;
   Date+1;
   output;
   end;
 run;
```

The result log shows an error... 'Insufficient space in file'

What I did as wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you have ETS licensed, then `PROC EXPAND` will do just this for you - that's exactly what it's for.

If you don't, you need to do something slightly different from what you did in your code.  `RETAIN` is helpful here.  You would need to do something similar but slightly different if there are other values you want and want to save *forward* instead of backwards (as my code will do) or if you want to do something else (like 'closest date').

```
data have;
input V1  $ Date :date7.;
datalines;
MS000328    04JAN16
MS000328    08JAN16
MS000328    12JAN16
MS000328    08FEB16
MS000328    09FEB16
MS000328    12MAR16
MS000328    15MAR16
MS000328    16APR16
MS000328    17APR16
MS000329    02JAN16
MS000329    16JAN16
MS000329    29JAN16
MS000329    03FEB16
MS000329    19FEB16
MS000329    21MAR16
MS000329    31MAR16
MS000329    11APR16
MS000329    19APR16
;;;;
run;

data want(rename=tempdate=date);
  set have;
  by v1;
  retain lastDate;
  drop date lastdate;

  if first.v1 then lastDate = '31DEC2015'd;  *lets us start on JAN 1;

  do tempdate = lastDate+1 to date;          *iterate from previous date + 1 to current date;
    output;
  end;

  if last.V1 then do;                        *if last record, need to iterate until DEC31, I think;
    do tempDate = date+1 to '31DEC2016'd;
      output;
    end;

  end;

  lastDate = date;                           *save current date for next iteration;
  format tempDate date9.;
run;
```

Comment: am I right in thinking that `proc expand` will only fill in the missing dates between the first and last in the data, i.e. it can't go before the first date or after the last date?

Comment: @Keith I think you're correct (That it will only interpolate inside the range), though that's easily enough fixed by adding single rows for the two start/end dates.  I would say that PROC EXPAND's value is mostly in dealing with the other variables on the dataset (it's easier, for example, to carry forward) and in its ability to impute values rather than just filling in; if it's just a matter of making rows, the above process is probably just as good given the start/end issue.

Comment: @Joe Thanks for yoúr help. We have license for SAS EG and couple of other SAS products  :)

Answer (score 0):

I was doubting that the process above would lead to memory issues....

still my answer is as follow...

```
Data Have;
  Input V1 $ Date Date9.;
  Format Date Date9.;
  Datalines;

MS000328    04JAN16
MS000328    08JAN16
MS000328    12JAN16
MS000328    08FEB16
MS000328    09FEB16
MS000328    12MAR16
MS000328    15MAR16
MS000328    16APR16
MS000328    17APR16
MS000329    02JAN16
MS000329    16JAN16
MS000329    29JAN16
MS000329    03FEB16
MS000329    19FEB16
MS000329    21MAR16
MS000329    31MAR16
MS000329    11APR16
MS000329    19APR16
;
Run;

/* Series of Dates */
Data Dates (Keep=Date);
  Format Date Date9.;
  Do i=0 To 365;
    Date=IntNX('day','01JAN2016'd,i);
    Output;
  End;
Run;

/* Vars */
Proc SQL;
  Create Table V1_IDs As Select Distinct V1 From Have Order By V1;
Quit;

/* series */
Proc SQL;
  Create Table Want As Select * From V1_IDs,Dates;
Quit;
```

Just let me know if any issues here...